# why null is greater than or equal to zero is true in node.js?

Tags: node.js

would like to know the detailed information

Comment: Perhaps not the best duplicate target... but basically, if you want the detailed information, [here's a link to the relevant part of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5)

Answer (score 0):

Greater than or equal to, means not smaller than. So if you do,

```
null >=0 means !(null < 0) which comes true
```

because

```
null < 0 is false.
```